# Adobe CQ5 - How to handle Session Timeout

Tags: aem

I want to know something about the Session Timeout on the Day CQSE HTTP Service. Is it possible to handle the exception that is thrown knowing that it is actually a Session Timeout Exception? I mean, on the controller part of the system (I use Java Spring), the exception I got is a NullPointerException after the timeout minutes has passed, and at this point the session is already reseted, making not possible to inform the user that his session has timed out, but only that "An error ocurred".

Thanks a lot,

Comment: What exactly do you want? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to tell the user that the CQ5 session timed out, as the only error I can catch is a Null Pointer Exception and the HTTPSession of the request object has been reseted (I can't get HTTPSession.getCreationTime(), it returns the current time).

Comment: on an author system you usually get redirected to the login screen with the message that your session timed out...